# How to pass variable into Mongoose "findByIdAndUpdate"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, variables, mongoose

Here's my code:

```
    app.post('/api/scheduleObject_Update', function(req, res) {



    var parameter = req.param('param');
    var value =  req.param('newvalue');
    var ID = "579918b5c25d87df3e3e69b6";
    console.log(parameter);


    Schedules.findByIdAndUpdate(ID, { parameter : value }, function(err, sched) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(sched);
    });


});
```

When it runs this Mongoose thinks "parameter" is what the field of my shcema is called when in reality I want the value stored in the variable "parameter." How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want dynamic keys in an object, you have to first create that object, and use bracket notation

```
app.post('/api/scheduleObject_Update', function(req, res) {

    var parameter = req.param('param');
    var value =  req.param('newvalue');
    var ID = "579918b5c25d87df3e3e69b6";

    var obj = {};            // create object
    obj[parameter] = value;  // set value

    Schedules.findByIdAndUpdate(ID, obj, function(err, sched) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(sched);
    });
});
```

Comment: OP you should really listen to this guy. With 197k reputation, he really knows his shit. Also his answer is correct. :D

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is:

```
Schedules.findByIdAndUpdate(ID, { [parameter] : value }, function(err, sched) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(sched);
    });
```